# VIM see regular expressions matches as you type

Tags: vim, regular-expression

If I type `/regex` then the cursor temporarily jumps to the first match and all matches are highlighted. This updates as I type. Is it possible to get this behavior when I'm getting ready to make a substitution? For instance, when I'm working on a complicated regular expression `:%s/\<regex\>/`, I would like to know what is matching before I pull the trigger and change everything. Any way to do it?

Comment: It would be nice if it would work in a way it works with the search: highlighting what currently matches.
Did you find the best way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type your search using **/** (or **?**) to begin with, which will allow you to tweak your regex (since you're using incsearch)

Once you get it all nice, you can use the **previous** search pattern  (the one you just used) in the substitute command by using two separators for the 'search' item:

```
/elephant                       " find the next elephant
:%s//rhino/gc                   " make then all rhinos!
```

Of course, you can use selections and ranges, as normal.

```
:1,15s,,cougar,g
:'<,'>s::tiger:
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `s//`

Answer (score 2):

One option is that you can have a confirmation flag `c`.

```
:%s;regex;replacement;gc
```

**`:h s_flags`**:

```
[c] Confirm each substitution.  Vim highlights the matching string.  You can type:              
        'y'     to substitute this match
        'l'     to substitute this match and then quit ("last")
        'n'     to skip this match
        <Esc>   to quit substituting
        'a'     to substitute this and all remaining matches
        'q'     to quit substituting
```

---

You can also try `grep` command to see the filtered output and the highlighted original file.

`:g/re/p` or `:g/re/`

Comment: I like it, but it still require me to complete the regular expression before I see what if anything was matched.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short way to see what your regular expression will match is doing a search with `/` using your desired regex. It will jump to the first match and mark it up while your're typing it. Try it - `vim` will not disappoint you.

Comment: True, though that's what I stated in the question. I wish it would update as I'm getting ready to substitute. With your solution I have to try the regex and then copy it (how?) and then use it in a substitution. That's not good enough.